# Вставить кусок php в html

Tags: php, html

Привет,

Есть стандартная форма HTML формы оплаты яндекс денег

```
<form action="https://money.yandex.ru/eshop.xml" method="post">
<input name="shopId" value="1234" type="hidden"/>
<input name="scid" value="4321" type="hidden"/>
<input name="sum" value="100.50" type="hidden">
<input name="customerNumber" value="abc000" type="hidden"/>
<input name="paymentType" value="AC" type="hidden"/>
<input name="orderNumber" value="abc1111111" type="hidden"/>
<input name="cps_phone" value="79110000000" type="hidden"/>
<input name="cps_email" value="user@domain.com" type="hidden"/>
```

Номер заказа генерируется в PHP документе, который сгенерирован с помощью конструктора. Вот кусок кода PHP в котором видно этот номер

```
<dt><?php echo RCUtilities::$localization->order->number; ?></dt>
                <dd><?php echo $this->cart->ID; ?></dd>
```

можно ли как-то подружить их и сделать так, чтобы в HTML от Яндекса в поле value orderNumber передавалась переменная из запроса echo
причем в сделать все это внутри html странички?

Answer (score 2):

```
<input name="orderNumber" value="<?php echo RCUtilities::$localization->order->number; ?>" type="hidden"/>
```

Comment: Подскажите, а как просто вывести эту переменную текстом, к примеру "заплатить" %переменная php% рублей?

Comment: заплатить <?php echo $переменная; ?> рублей

Comment: увы ваше предложение не работает - почему то прямо так текстом и передается:Сумма100,50 Р
Номер заказа<?php echo RCUtilities::$localization->order->number; ?>
Идентификатор плательщикаabc000

Comment: файл с каким расширением? php вообще установлен?

Comment: .html     php не установлен, в смысле его подключить надо?

Comment: ну а как вы пытаетесь вывести переменную php без интерпретатора?Я сейчас еще и сомневаюсь что вообще подключен класс RCUtilities...Советую либо начать учить php либо заказывать работу на фрилансе

Comment: не думал, что это так замороченно, учитывая что вопрос был по html. вы не сердитесь. Пишу на питоне, думал что в броузерных языках переменные должны передаваться легко и разбираться тут особо не надо. Я правильно вас понял, что надо на страницу html подключить класс RCUtilities и еще возможно интерпретатор?

Comment: PHP - серверный язык

Comment: последний ваш ответ малоинформативен. По гуглу беда я уже кучу страниц перерыл. Больше всего смущает что нигде не увидел в примерах, что надо что-то подключать к html, что странно потому что именно в это, как я понимаю является проблемой у меня. может, вы подскажете более развернуто?

Comment: что б использовать переменные PHP, вам для начала нужно его установить. А каким образом и из чего вы получаете эту переменную-второй вопрос